# Missing piece in Sentry-raven to Sentry-ruby guide

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, sentry

I'm in the middle of migrating our existing application from Sentry-raven to Sentry-ruby. There appears to be a missing piece in the migration guide, however.

What do I do with #sanitize_fields?

The old config looked like this:

```rb
 Raven.configure do |config|
   config.sanitize_fields = filter_parameters
 end
```

However, #sanitize_fields was removed and I don't see anywhere where the functionality was replaced.

We used this to ensure that passwords and confirmations were not sent to Sentry (bad day), so I need something to do that in using sentry-ruby.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: go-through the comments on [issue](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-ruby/issues/1140) in `sentry-ruby`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Great suggestion from Sampat. To save future readers having to go through all the comments, the summary is:

1. If you're using Rails you can use this snippet:

```rb
  filter = ActiveSupport::ParameterFilter.new(Rails.application.config.filter_parameters)

  config.before_send = lambda do |event, hint|
    filter.filter(event.to_hash)
  end
```

2. Alternatively use [this gem](https://github.com/mrexox/sentry-sanitizer), developed to replace the previous sanitization functionality

Answer (score 1):

Yes I had the same issue here.

Here some options for Rails 6 and 5.

This example uses Rails' parameter filter to sanitize the event payload

##### for Rails 6+

```
  filter = ActiveSupport::ParameterFilter.new(Rails.application.config.filter_parameters)
```

##### for Rails 5

```
  filter = ActionDispatch::Http::ParameterFilter.new(Rails.application.config.filter_parameters)

  config.before_send = lambda do |event, hint|
    filter.filter(event.to_hash)
  end
```